# Return a digit in the middle of a string regex

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm not sure how to do a regexp_replace to return a digit in the middle of the string.

My current string is : "Game of Thrones S2 Ep6" and I need to return the Season number from this. My current regex does the job correctly but takes two regexp expressions:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('Game of Thrones S1 Ep12', r'(^[^_]*\sS)', ''), r'(\s*Ep\s*\d*\s*$)', '')
```

Some other test entries are:

> "Smallville S 10 Ep 12"
>
> "The Days of Our Lives S26 Ep324"

This first Strips off the text up to and including the first " S".
Then splits off the end of the string up to and including the whitespace before "Ep"

Can someone please give me a capture group that allows this to be done in one replace. This is a very costly query at the moment.

Comment: What I don't understand is - why the *replace* approach at all? Why not just capture the season number with a regex, like - `\bS\s*(\d+)\s*Ep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capturing group around the season number `(\d+)` and replace with a backreference (`'\1'`):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('Game of Thrones S1 Ep12', r'^[^\n_]*\sS\s*(\d+)\s*Ep\s*\d*\s*$', r'\1')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT3nQ4/1)

Note that I am just extending your own regex, you might want to also check `r'^.*\sS\s*(\d+).*'` regex that will get the last space + `S` with one or more digits after them.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT3nQ4/2)

Comment: Sorry, the demo link got corrupt, fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) function, not REGEXP_REPLACE.
With Standard SQL, example query would look like following:

```
select regexp_extract(text, r'[sS][ ]*(\d+)') from (
select text from unnest(["Smallville S 10 Ep 12", "The Days of Our Lives S26 Ep324"]) text)
```

and it returns

```
Row f0_  
1   10   
2   26
```